# error with date in query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need some help with this query:

```
update MSG_TRACE set MSG_SENT_STATUS = 'INIT',ERROR_CODE = 0,RETRY_COUNT = 0 where MSG_RECEIVED_TIME >= '16-01-2012 00:00:00,000000' and OPER_TXN_ID like 'CAP%' and MSG_SENT_STATUS in ('FAILED','ERROR');
```

It gives me this error: **ORA-01843: not a valid month**

The MSG_RECEIVED_TIME is in the format DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS.mmmmmm
like 16/01/2012 02:46:34.729643 PM

thank you very much in advance

Comment: What date format is your oracle install using? If it's set to MM/DD/YY that's your problem.

Comment: @SimonRigharts i also tried it with '01-16-2012 00:00:00,000000' and got the same error

Comment: @FahimParkar its actually TIMESTAMP(6)

Comment: does problem solve by changing the date ?

Comment: can you provide your table structure?? Use command `describe TableName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The milliseconds part means it is not a date. You need to cast to a timestamp such as:

```
select to_timestamp('16-01-2012 00:00:00,000000','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss,FF')
from dual
```

If you need it to be a date format then you can cast it further:

```
select to_date(
         to_char(
           to_timestamp('16-01-2012 00:00:00,000000'
                       ,'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss,FF')
          ,'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
        ,'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  from dual
```

Comment: if i try select (*) from MSG_TRACE where MSG_RECEIVED_TIME >= select to_timestamp('16-01-2012 00:00:00,000000','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss,FF') from dual it gives me ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: Wrap the sub-query in brackets and remove them from around the asterisk: `select * from MSG_TRACE where MSG_RECEIVED_TIME >= (select to_timestamp('16-01-2012 00:00:00,000000','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss,FF') from dual)`

Answer (score 0):

Your data base configured to be `MM/DD/YYYY` so 16/01/2012 isn't valid because there is not 16 month. you have three options:

1. Change 16/01/2012 to 01/16/2012.
2. Change your DB to be DD/MM/YYYY
3. Try add the 16 month to our calenders... =)

Answer (score 0):

`'01-16-2012 00:00:00,000000'` is incorrect... try with `'16-01-2012 00:00:00'`

Also your date is INCORRECT...

`ORA-01843: not a valid month` error is coming as you are setting month as `16` which is INCORRECT...

Date format in timestamp is as below

`DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS:MM`